# get_file() error in google colab R enviroment

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I have this error:

> Error in get_file(fname = "flores.zip", origin = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?export=download&confirm=sgo2&id=107ocoPLxNddbHp2MDsIWIYX9qb196WUv", : argument "file" is missing, with no default

Here is My code:

```r
data_dir <- get_file(fname ="flores.zip",
                     origin ="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?export=download&confirm=sgo2&id=107ocoPLxNddbHp2MDsIWIYX9qb196WUv",
                     extract = TRUE
                    )

data_dir <- file.path(dirname(data_dir), "flores")

images <- list.files(data_dir, pattern = ".jpg", recursive = TRUE)

length(images)
```

In my desktop version RStudio works! But not in google colab R enviroment

can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Natalia. It would be helpful to have more information when you ask a question here. For example, the get_file function is imported from the Keras package. You should have included the library(keras) call at the beginning of the code snippet. You should also include a dummy dataset or file so we can test things on our system. I can't use that link or file to check what would happen on my system.
EDIT: I actually ran your code through a notebook and it worked. The directory had no images in it, but it ran just fine.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I will try again so, thank for your help.